# Inserting Data from Flat file source to database between 2 dates

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS package set up that imports downloaded data files to the database (one file at a time by date)

Current Setup (for a file):

1. Downloaded file is at location (same file exists between the date range 1st Feb to Today)

   > C:\DataFiles\GeneralSale_20170201.txt
2. In SSIS the variables - For each file there are 4 variables. First is the location of the where the file is, called `@Location`
3. The second simple gives the name of the file named `@GeneralSales` returning the value

   > GeneralSale_
4. The third is the date (`@ExportDateFormatted`) for which the code is, `(DT_WSTR,8)(DATEPART("yyyy", @[User::ExportDate]) * 10000 + DATEPART("mm", @[User::ExportDate]) * 100 + DATEPART("dd", @[User::ExportDate]))` and `[ExportDate]` is set as `DATEADD("DD", 0, GETDATE())`.

   `[ExportDate]` allows me to set the file date (which is already downloaded) that I want to import in my table `dbo.GeneralSale` i.e. If I want to import the file on 20170205 then I would adjust the export date and then run the package
5. The final variable is the `@ExportFileExtension` returning the value

   > txt
6. Then in the DataFlow which looks like the below:

[image]

The flat file source connects to the connection string below. The `Property > Expressions > ConnectionString` of the connection string runs the variables to make a file name. This is where I use the variables from before

```
@[User::Location] + @[User::GeneralSales] +  @[User::ExportDateFormatted] + "." +  @[User::ExportFileExtension]
```

Returning the value:

> C:\DataFiles\GeneralSale_20170201.txt

This then populates the table with the data of that file. But to insert the date for another day I have to amend the date and run the package.

**What I am trying to do is pass a start and end date to let the package insert all data from the files between those dates.**

Hope the above information is clear of what goes on and what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: That's a little tricky but possible with the use of a calendar table. My question is: why not just import all the data permanently into a table then select from the table based on dates?

Comment: I do want to import all data in once but the data is downloaded each day, hence why the data variables to allow me to go back and import the missed data files. I am trying to change the way it works and pass a start and end date and the package to go and import data files between those dates

Comment: I suggest a more robust approach is to just import everything you find in your source folder. When a file is successfully imported, move it to a 'processed' folder. Every day you just import whatever arrives in your folder.  This is a tried and true pattern used successfully over and over. It automatically processes late arrivals (if that is the issue - not sure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate between two dates. In SSIS its pretty straightforward; I would describe the main steps:

1. Define two package parameters, `StartDate` and `EndDate` of type Date, and on the package start - validate that `StartDate <= EndDate`.
2. Define a Date variable `ExtrDate`, and add **For Loop** with settings initial Expression `@ExtrDate = @StartDate`, Evaluation - `@ExtrDate <= @EndDate` and Assign - `@ExtrDate = DateAdd("dd", 1, @ExtrDate)`. Purpose of this loop is quite clear.
3. Put your extraction tasks inside **For Loop** container.

`ExtrDate` variable will be increased on each step of the loop.
Package parameters allow building more flexible package.